# Copy and paste entire song in GarageBand for iPad

Tags: ios, ipados, garageband

In GarageBand for iPad, how do I get my song to repeat, so that the song is played twice its duration?

The song has ten tracks and 25 sections. I just want to select all and copy-paste the whole song at the end of the song so it’s twice as long and repeated once.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your project is too big? I have heard that GarageBand, even on a Mac, has limitations when the project gets too big. It would refuse an operation or just hang or crash without much feedback. Try with a much smaller/simpler test song and see if you can accomplish what you want. Or try posting exactly the steps you do to copy and paste, and exactly what happens (what GarageBand does) after.